# Can Anyone Tell me the difference between get() and all() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

$record = Record::all();

$record::where('user_id',1)->get();

Answer (score 1):

`Record::all()` and `Record::get()` are the same thing.

However `all()` is a static method on the Eloquent\Model. What is does is create a new query object and call `get()` on the new object. With `all()` you're unable to modify the performed query.

`get()` is a method on the Eloquent\Builder object. `get()` is useful if you need to modify you're query, like adding a where clause for example.

Answer (score 0):

with all() you cannot modify the query
get() you can modify  the query such as adding a where to it.